# react-stockcharts with Json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, unix-timestamp

Hello guys I am trying to implement React-stockchart into my project however i am running into an issue that i have been facing since few days now with the data that i need to pass to the chart.

**React-stockchart accept Data in this format**

```
 Data=[
    0:{
       open:25.436282332605284 , 
       high:25.835021381744056 , 
       low: 25.411360259406774,
       date:Date 2010-01-03T23:00:00.000Z,
       volume:38409100},
    1:{....}
    2:{....}
]
```

Using this function i was able to convert my entry data from this format [My data](https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1m:tBTCUSD/hist) to this format

the function that i use to convert the data into a similair format that React-Stockchart accept:

```
convertData(data) {
      var keys = ["date","open","close","hight","low","volume"],
          i = 0, k = 0,
          obj = null,
          output = [];
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          obj = {};
          for (k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
              obj[keys[k]] = data[i][k];
          }
      output.push(obj);
      }
    return output;
  }
```

after using this function i got a result in this format , however the date is in unix timestamp and i am looking for a way to implement into my function to get the date into a similair format that React-stockchart accept

```
Data=[
        0:{
           open:10608 , 
           high:10617 , 
           low: 10613.07326842,
           date:1519288380000,
           volume:25.33908407},
        1:{....}
        2:{....}
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Date object with the timestamp:

```
var dateObj = new Date(timestamp);
```

so in your situation:

```
convertData(data) {
      var keys = ["date","open","close","hight","low","volume"],
          i = 0, k = 0,
          obj = null,
          output = [];
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          obj = {};
          obj[keys[0]] = new Date(data[i][0]); 
          for (k = 1; k < keys.length; k++) {
              obj[keys[k]] = data[i][k];
          }
      output.push(obj);
      }
    return output;
  }
```

Comment: You can also try obj[keys[0]] = new Date(data[i][0]).toISOString();
in case it accepts a String formatted like this.

Comment: Oh thanks man it working now , believe it or not i was stuck in this problem for more than 3 days , really man thank you a lot for taking the time to answer